# Problems with <% %> and Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, ejs

I am using **EJS** with **Node** in **Visual Studio code**. I have a problem with the characters **<%- somevar %>** and the format of the html. The HTML formatter insert a line break automatically when detects the character <%

For example, I see the line :

```
        <p class="copyright">Todos los derechos reservados - Meeti
                <%- year %> </p>
```

(the HTML formatter break this in two lines):

I would like see this line as:

```
        <p class="copyright">Todos los derechos reservados - Meeti <%- year %> </p>
```

All in one line

Someone has experienced this kind of behavior. How could I configure Visual Studio code?

Many Thanks!

## UPDATE

The problem was one extension installed in Visual Studio Code. The extension is https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter

I hope this help someone.